# How to analyse disk performance issues visible in Windows Resource Monitor?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, performance, resource-monitor

I'm using Windows Resource Monitor and I observe poor response times of >250ms. I know which application is ultimately requesting the files, but the disk access is monitored under the System process.

I can be reasonably sure that the problem is not caused by disk hardware issues.

But what is causing this? Is there a way to see where in the IO stack the time is spent? Is there a way to "visualize" the IO stack, see what filters, monitoring tools, anti-virus tools and whatnot are working on the file before my application gets the contents?

Comment: Take a look at [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx): "Process Monitor is an advanced monitoring tool for Windows that shows real-time file system, Registry and process/thread activity. ... including rich and non-destructive filtering, comprehensive event properties such session IDs and user names, reliable process information, full thread stacks with integrated symbol support for each operation, simultaneous logging to a file"

Comment: No, procmon doesn't really help - it does show the correct originating process for the requests, but it doesn't show the duration and it doesn't show where the time is spent either.

Comment: check xperf/WPA: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-44-WPT-DiskIO-Analysis